# Compare list or set on part of the JSON object

Tags: json, python-2.7, set

This is how my Input looks like:

```
inputData=[]
inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerA","State": "StateA","ItemNumber": "Item1"})
inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerA","State": "StateA","ItemNumber": "Item2"})
inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerB","State": "StateB","ItemNumber": "Item1"})
inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerB","State": "StateB","ItemNumber": "Item2"})
inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerX","State": "StateX","ItemNumber": "Item1"})
inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerX","State": "StateX","ItemNumber": "Item2"})
```

This is the list I am comparing against to find out if the Customer is allowed to buy the item or not.

```
allowedCustomers = ["CustomberA","CustomberB"]
```

This is how i am comparing the lists:

```
unauthorizedCustomers = list(set(inputData)-set(allowedCustomers))
```

How do modify above statement so that the comparison happens only on CustomerName but unauthorizedCustomers list has `CustomerX`'s full data?

```
[{"CustomerName": "CustomerX","State": "StateX","ItemNumber": "Item1"},
{"CustomerName": "CustomerX","State": "StateX","ItemNumber": "Item2"})]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> inputCustomerNames = [ item['CustomerName'] for item in inputData ] # get a list of input customer names only
>>> unauthorizedCustomers = list(set(inputCustomerNames) - set(allowedCustomers)) # find unauthorized customers
>>> unauthorizedCustomersDetails = [ item for item in inputData if item['CustomerName'] in unauthorizedCustomers ] # get all data of unauthorized customers
```

You should read about list comprehensions to understand what is happening here. [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do using json and lists:

```
 import json
 inputData=[]
 inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerA","State": "StateA","ItemNumber": "Item1"})
 inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerA","State": "StateA","ItemNumber": "Item2"})
 inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerB","State": "StateB","ItemNumber": "Item1"})
 inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerB","State": "StateB","ItemNumber": "Item2"})
 inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerX","State": "StateX","ItemNumber": "Item1"})
 inputData.append({"CustomerName": "CustomerX","State": "StateX","ItemNumber": "Item2"})

 allowedCustomers = ["CustomerA","CustomerB"]
 json_array = json.loads(json.dumps(inputData))
 # Now filter required customer based on specific property.
 allowed_customers = [customer for customer in json_array if customer['CustomerName'] in allowedCustomers]
```